# Return row when one of many conditions is not met

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get a list of IDs and a corresponding field from a table where the ID may not exist. For example, the table looks like:

```
 id  | status
-------------
1234 | A
4567 | B
1020 | C
```

I want to get the status from rows with `id=4567` and `id=7777`, like this:

```
Result:
 id  | status
-------------
4567 | B
7777 |
```

Since there is no record with id=7777 it should show an empty status field.

What I have so far: I can get an empty row when there is no record for any of the ID matches by joining the result with `DUAL`. For example:

```
SELECT id, status FROM DUAL LEFT OUTER JOIN mytable ON id='7777'
```

Gives the result of an empty row:

```
 id  | status
-------------
     |
```

But adding a valid id to the condition only returns one row:

```
SELECT id, status FROM mytable WHERE (id='7777' OR id='4567')

 id  | status
-------------
4567 | B
```

How can I make the query return a row with the requested ID even if it has no record?

Comment: I can't make sense of your tables... what is DUAL?

Comment: @Adam: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DUAL_table

Comment: @Adam: DUAL is a dummy table use by Oracle when you don't want to use a table. For example SELECT 1 FROM DUAL.

Comment: @Quassnoi ah cheers, didn't spot the Oracle tag either - I'll shut the door on my way out.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth `FROM DUAL` exists in MySQL as well according to [`SELECT` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html), though MySQL's parser is smart enough to infer `FROM DUAL` automatically where needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  q.id, m.status
FROM    (
        SELECT  4567 AS id
        FROM    dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  7777 AS id
        FROM    dual
        ) q
LEFT JOIN
        mytable m
ON      m.id = q.id
```

Comment: This works quite well. It puts in a row of NULLs for each id with no result. However, I need the row of NULLs to contain the id that had no matches. Is this possible?

Comment: PERFECT! thanks so much! This makes a lot of sense to me now.

Answer (score 0):

Let outer join returns value from a table (on the left) even when there is no corresponding record in the other joined table. (right outer join is same, except that it returns data from the table on the right even if there is no corresponding record in the table on the left)

Meaning you need to have data in at least one table to get it in the result.

Actually this is the reason why you get data for `4567`. You have a record corresponding to 4567 in the left table (and not in `dual`).

You don't have `7777` in either of the tables, and that's why it does not come in the result.

You have two options here
one, as @Quassnoi has said, you can select all the records from dual, and left join with the other table.
This might not be practical if your data is dynamic or if you have a lot of data.
In that case you can create a small temp table with your data and then join with the other table. To make a long story short: you need to have the data somewhere so that you join with this other table.

Comment: Is it possible to create a temporary table inside a `select` query? I only have read access.

Comment: @hughes From where is your data coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Use `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` instead of `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: Not sure what the result of that was, but the query timed out when I tried it. It's a large table with about a million rows.

Answer (score 0):

With a temporary table, where you store 4567 and 7777, or an appropriate query, you could do a union:

```
SELECT DISTINCT n, '' 
  FROM tmp, tbl 
  WHERE n NOT IN (SELECT id FROM tbl) 
UNION (
SELECT id, status 
  FROM tmp, tbl 
  WHERE n=id);
```

I tested it on postgresql - it might differ from the syntax on oracle.

Comment: I did not see a hint on read-only access. Is this a new info? Since I don't have oracle installed, I don't know. I guess not. Don't you get the ids from a query? Postgresql has some pseudo-tables to generate arrays, which I'm not firm with, but of course the syntax, if oracle has something similar, will be very different. But isn't DUAL a candidate again?